# jQuery toggleClass fade works with one class, not with the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my `i` elements to lose the `outline` class on hover, but for some reason this is not working. The class is lost and added again instantly without a fade/delay. If I try this exact same code with a class of `background` then it does work. What am I not seeing here?

The second problem is that when I do try this with a `background` class, the background stays there for the duration of the fade (in this case 500ms) and then disappears instantly. This should also be a fade, like a fade out.

Thank you!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erL8x2rd/45/)

```
$('nav a').hover(function(){
  if (!$(this).find("i").hasClass("home")){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('outline', 500);
    }
})
```

Comment: The second parameter to `toggleClass` is the `state` which should be a `Boolean` value. http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hover()` can be passed 2 functions as arguments. The first is like `.mouseover()` and the second is the `.mouseout()`

```
$('nav a').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.home').removeClass('outline');
}, function() {
  $('.home').addClass('outline');
})
```

**Update**

You can add fadein and fadeout effect without Javascript, only with css:

```
nav {
    font-size: 20 px;
}
nav a {
    padding-left: 30 px;
}
nav a i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
nav a i.star: not(.outline) {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 300 ms ease;
}
nav a: hover.star: not(.outline) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300 ms ease;
}
```

**[Demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/106287/)**

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ and https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/ Not sure what the 500 is doing here

Comment: This doesn't work as mouseover and mouseout, since the class is not added back when you stop hovering. There's also no fade/delay, so I'm not sure what it is supposed to fix. Did you your code first?

Comment: As he said: I want my i elements to lose the outline class on hover.
If I understand, whe the user hover on the `a` element, it adds class to the `i` if this `a` hasclass home! :D

Comment: @Gerard, weird copy and paste! sorry! ;)

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Check my Fiddle, it's already doing that, but I need it to fade in/out on hover and that's missing. Try replacing your code for mine in the Fiddle, you'll see that it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated with css transition or jQuery animation method

Comment: Your new demo works, but it only seems to work with a normal css class, not with a Semantic UI icon. Do you think there is a way to make it work for the actual icon?

Comment: Provide fiddle with UI icon first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168733/discussion-between-sirexotic-and-radonirina-maminiaina).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Radonirina Maminiaina][1]'s answer and some altering of the code by myself I made it work exactly as intended.

It was Radonirina's idea to put the second icon right behind the original icon by using `position: absolute;` (see his code above), but then I came up with the idea to add the class `"dark"` to the hidden icon underneath and simply select it to make the opacity 0, and 1 on hover, including the transition effect. This made the CSS a lot simpler and it works beautifully.

Thanks again!

Here is a working example of the end result:

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open', 500);
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
/* Navigation bar */

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666666;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: Fjalla One;
}

.smallNav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-open {
  height: auto;
}

.smallNav a {
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5em 4em 1.5em 3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
}

.smallNav a:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.smallNav a:hover,
.smallNav a:focus {
  color: #222;
  background: #BABABA;
}

/* Menu toggle */

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 0.75em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.menu-toggle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

i.icon {
  margin-right: 0.5em !important;
  font-size: 1.2em !important;
}

/* Change icons on hover */
nav a i.dark {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42px;
}
nav a i.dark {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
nav a:hover i.dark {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
nav a:hover i.outline {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="header-container">

    <nav class="smallNav">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li><i class="icon home"></i>Home</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><i class="icon star outline"></i><i class="icon star dark"></i>Featured</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><i class="icon newspaper outline"></i><i class="icon newspaper dark"></i>News</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><i class="icon user outline"></i><i class="icon user dark"></i>Career</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><i class="icon envelope outline"></i><i class="icon envelope dark"></i>Contact</li></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```